# Почтовое событие в битрикс 1с не присылает данные из формы?

Tags: битрикс

Доброе утро! У меня возникла проблема с почтовым событием в битрикс. Письмо отправляется но данные не приходят. Точнее приходит шаблон, но без данных из формы.

```
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
?>

    <?$USER_NAME=htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST['usernameLizing']);
      $USER_TEL=htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST['telLizing']);
    $USER_EMAIL=htmlspecialcharsbx($_POST['emailLizing']);
    $arEventFields=array(
    "USER_NAME"=>'имя',
    "USER_TEL"=>$USER_TEL,
    "USER_EMAIL"=>$USER_EMAIL
    );
    
    CEvent::Send("RASCHET_LIZING", "s1", $arEventFields,"N","","");
    
    ?>
Почтовый шаблон:
Проверьте Ваш расчет по лизингу


Имя:#USER_NAME#
Номер телефона: #USER_TEL#
Email:#USER_EMAIL#
```

Comment: А зачем вы здесь используете htmlspecialcharsbx, а не htmlspecialchars? htmlspecialcharsbx как раз убирает из входной строки то, что пришло в $_POST.

Comment: @ВикторКарев в видео в ютубе использовалось. Но по чему то все равно не работает. Данные отправляю по ajax и они уходят.

Comment: я попробовал передать строку "USER_NAME"=>'имя' , но у меня все равно ничего не приходит

Comment: Проверьте таблицу b_event, в таблицу 'имя' заносится?

Comment: Проверьте шаблоны, возможно, у вас подключается другой шаблон к этому событию.

Comment: Да сейчас еще раз проверил- заносится и строка 'имя ' все таки приходит. А данные с формы почему то не передаются

Comment: Данные с формы не приходят, потому что они удаляются функцией htmlspecialcharsbx. Эта функция нужна для борьбы с межсайтовым скриптингом (XSS). В вашем случае она вредна.

Comment: <?$USER_NAME=htmlspecialchars($_POST['usernameLizing']); написал так , но все равно не приходит

Comment: Тогда только проверить, что вообще приходит в $_POST - ```print_r($_POST)```. Кстати, а передача данных точно происходит методом POST, а не GET? Может, логичнее будет использовать $_REQUEST?

Comment: Request URL:
http://ct53455-bitrix-1srj2.tw1.ru/post-event/send2.php
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
92.53.96.41:80
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Запрос отправляю post , но print_r($_POST) показывает пусто почему то

Comment: Ну, вот тут и надо копать. Почему в POST не уходят данные.

Comment: @ВикторКарев, спасибо за помощь!